# Java OOP with serialization, file is not being loaded

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to create a form where the user saves three pieces of information (id, name and surname). The following is the code of the person:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

private String Personfirstname;
private String Personlastname;
private String PersonID;

/**
 * @return the Personfirstname
 */
public String getPersonfirstname() {
    return Personfirstname;
}

/**
 * @param Personfirstname the Personfirstname to set
 */
public void setPersonfirstname(String Personfirstname) {
    this.Personfirstname = Personfirstname;
}

/**
 * @return the Personlastname
 */
public String getPersonlastname() {
    return Personlastname;
}

/**
 * @param Personlastname the Personlastname to set
 */
public void setPersonlastname(String Personlastname) {
    this.Personlastname = Personlastname;
}

/**
 * @return the PersonID
 */
public String getPersonID() {
    return PersonID;
}

/**
 * @param PersonID the PersonID to set
 */
public void setPersonID(String PersonID) {
    this.PersonID = PersonID;
}  


 public void savecons()
{
    try {
        File selectedFile = new File("Consultant - " + PersonID + ".txt");
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
        oos.writeObject(this);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private String toString(int ConsultantID) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}  


public static Person loadcons() throws Exception
{
    Person loadcons = null;

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int chooserOption = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;

        try {
            File file = new File (chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));


        loadcons = (Person) input.readObject();
            input.close();
       return loadcons;
   } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
   throw new Exception("No files were selected");
}

private String toString(String PersonID) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

The code have the 3 variables and 2 methods. One of the methods saves the variable information into a text files (the text files is being outputted but I am not sure if the information is getting into it as its all symbols. The other method is a load button that will import the data back in the fields.

Then I created a form with the following code. There the saving is:

```
 Person cons_save = new Person();
    cons_save.setPersonfirstname(this.jTextField1.getText());
    cons_save.setPersonlastname(this.jTextField2.getText());
    cons_save.setPersonID(this.jTextField3.getText());
    this.jTextField1.setText("");
    this.jTextField2.setText("");
    this.jTextField3.setText("");

    cons_save.savecons();
```

and the loading is the below:

```
Person cons_load = Person.loadcons();
        this.jTextField1.setText(cons_load.getPersonfirstname());
        this.jTextField2.setText(cons_load.getPersonlastname());
        this.jTextField3.setText(cons_load.getPersonID());
```

When I press the loading button it doesn't work as it needs an exception but when I create the exception the button works but when I chose the file, the information is not going to the fields.

```
 Person cons_load;
    try {
        cons_load = Person.loadcons();
        this.jTextField1.setText(cons_load.getPersonfirstname());
        this.jTextField2.setText(cons_load.getPersonlastname());
        this.jTextField3.setText(cons_load.getPersonID());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateConsultant.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I appreciate every help I can get as this is the first time I am trying to program in java oop.

Comment: So, you get an exception and are wondering why. Then post the exception stack trace. It tells you why. My guess is that the exception is caused by you not closing the ObjectOutputStream. Oh, and as npinti correctly mentions: your class must be serializable. Don't catch the IOException in savecons(): it hides the bug. And respect the Java naming conventions. And give meaningful names to your methods. What does savecons mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to mark the classes you want to save to file with the [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. This should allow the serialization of the objects you are after.

As per the JavaDoc (I highlighted some text in bold):

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. **Classes that do not implement this
>   interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.**
>   All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable. The
>   serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to
>   identify the semantics of being serializable.

Essentially, this: `public class Person` needs to become this: `public class Person implements Serializable { static final long serialVersionUID = ...`.

It is important that `serialVersionUID` is unique for each class since it is used for serialization and deserialization purposes.

EDIT: As per the comments below, I copied your code and ran it. I managed to save and read it back without issues. The code ran as is in your question, seeing that you have added the marker interface (it is good practice to also include your `serialVersionUID` field).

I then removed the `implements Serializable` section of your code, and I got this error: `writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: so.Person`. This essentially shows that you are trying to store a non serializable item.

Below is what the content of the file looks like when the exception is thrown:

[image: Error thrown during serialization of non serializable item.]

Comment: So I marked the person to implement Serializable as an interface but still the same issue keeps occurring. But thanks for this point I forgot to included. I will edit my post

Comment: That would have been my answer, too. I tested the supplied code and wondered why the serialization works even if the `Person` class is not `Serializable`? The file gets actually created! I would have expected the exception already on saving the Person object to a file

Comment: @beosign the OP catches the IOException and basically ignores it. What he sees in the file is the serialization header written as soon as an ObjectOutputStream is created, I presume.

Comment: @RyanTheuma: I've updated my answer and your current version of the code seems to be working, at least it did for me. Are you sure you are not trying to read an older version of the file?

Comment: @beosign: Although the file *is* created, what is written in it is essentially a strack trace, at least that is what I can make out of the content of the file.

Comment: @JBNizet: I do not know about the serialization header (could be, I have some weird characters at the beginning of the file) but most of the contents of the file appear to be some stack trace.

Comment: I don't see how it could contain a stack trace. Do you know what a stack trace is? It's what is printed on the console when doing calling someException.printStackTrace(). What you see in the file is binary data, not text, because Java Serialization uses a binary format, not a textual one like JSON or XML.

Comment: @npinti Thjats what as the issue, I was using an older file. Thanks very much for the help all of you

Comment: @JBNizet: It is not *exactly* a stack trace as it is printed in the console, but there is information as to what exception was thrown and in which method it failed. I've included an image in my answer.

Comment: @npinti You're absolutely right, I overlooked the `catch` block, thanks!